# Flag as duplicate option on Area51

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, area-51, flags, duplicate-questions

When browsing Area51, I came across a proposal which was an exact duplicate of another proposal.  ([this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43984/ask-google) and [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42308/google)).

When I went to flag it, I saw there was no option for flagging as a duplicate.

[image: Flagging a proposal on Area51]

Shouldn't this feature be added and if not why is that feature not there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still flag it as a duplicate - just type in a message in that textbox. :)

We aren't making any serious code changes to Area 51 at this point as we work on our [next generation proposal system](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5926/26022).